# Christian denominations that view Jesus as a human moral teacher?

Tags: denomination-survey, morality

Are there any current Christian denominations that view Jesus as a human moral teacher, rather than as the supernatural Son of God?  I am looking for specific examples of denominations that state this viewpoint (or some variation) as part of their creed.

Comment: I believe only the Jehovah's Witnesses profess this type of view.

Comment: Maybe also nontheist Friends.

Comment: That’s because there is no other alternative to characterize Him. That is the next best compromised position.

Comment: some Unitarians maybe?

Comment: Christian Scientests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unitarian Universalists maintain the Jesus was only a man, but with a unique relationship to God. Unitarians makeup the majority of a sect of Christianity known as nontrinitarianism. Nontrinitarians reject many parts of christian doctrine that other sects find essential. The most notably difference is their rejection of the concept of the Holy Trinity, the idea that God, the Holy Spirit, and Jesus Christ are all equal parts to a whole. This rejection of the trinity leads to the belief that Jesus was not supernatural but only a great prophet. Other belief systems that maintain this are:  Christadelphians, Christian Scientists, The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, Dawn Bible Students, Friends General Conference, Iglesia ni Cristo, Jehovah's Witnesses, Living Church of God, Oneness Pentecostals, Members Church of God International, and the United Church of God. Islam and the sects of several sects of Judaism maintain the Jesus was only a great prophet as well.

Comment: Judaism tends to consider Jesus as a false prophet - can you provide a reference to a sect that considers him to be a prophet of God?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I meant to say Messianic Jews, which may or may not be considered Jewish depending on your belief system. The main sects of Judaism consider Jesus to be a false messiah. I apologize for the oversight.

Comment: Unitarian Universalism does not merely offer a different dogma than other churches. It is more radical: it opposes dogma. It substitutes a free and open search for truth, and offers an environment that encourages and supports searchers. Consequently, UU takes no position on the divinity of Jesus. That is left to individual conscience.

Answer (score -1):

I think people or community or denomination can't call themselves as "Christian" if they were considering Jesus as a human moral teacher, rather than as the supernatural Son of God.
Still there are a lot of communities sharing that viewpoint and sometimes are considered to be "Christian" although they are not "Christian" like Jehovah's Witnesses or early (or later) heresies.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Christianity SE! When you get a moment you may want to see the [about] page and find out [what makes us different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/4188). This is going to sound odd, but [we're not actually a Christian site](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/193/4188). We are not so much about sharing opinions (or even the actual truth of Christianity) but rather the teachings of various groups that call themselves Christians -- including Jehovah's Witnesses.

Comment: Does that mean that I should delete my comment?